# Eclipse file search regex to include search phrase and exclude particular strings

Tags: regex, eclipse, search

This is for all you regex hounds.

I need to filter my search in eclipse when I do a file search.

I am looking for `aTracker` but this brings back hundreds of results so I want to be able to thin the results out.

First off I would like to remove `aTracker.sendException` and possibly others.

[image]

This is a common problem for me so I'm finally posting for a solution so I don't need to go fetch my waders every time a search like this comes along.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match all `aTracker` except `aTracker.sendException`, you can use a negative lookahead if eclipse supports it:

```
aTracker(?!\.sendException)
```

You should check the 'Regular expression' box I think.

Comment: Thank you this works. However, what if I also wanted to exclude `aTracker =` or `aTracker=` etc. How can I add future strings?

Comment: @Haraldo It will make the regex longer, but you can do it by using an 'or' like this: `aTracker(?!\.sendException| =|=)` except that you can shorten it as you have an optional space: `aTracker(?!\.sendException| ?=)`. ` ?` (space and `?` means 0 or 1 space).